# Select row in HTML table to update chart selection?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angularjs, d3.js, html-table

How do I setup an HTML+JS table with data associated to a chart (Flotr or D3); where I can multiselect rows and that will update what is shown in the chart? - I'll likely be using AngularJS, so their two-way data-binding might be of help...

E.g.:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
         <tr><th>Vowel</th> <th>Amount</th></tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr> <td>A</td> <td>3</td> </tr>
         <tr> <td>E</td> <td>6</td> </tr>
         <tr> <td>I</td> <td>7</td> </tr>
         <tr> <td>O</td> <td>8</td> </tr>
         <tr> <td>U</td> <td>9</td> </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: pie graph]

Would also be great to be able to go reverse as well, e.g.: pressing `E` and `A` on the pie graph would refresh the pie-graph + the table.

Comment: what kind of update do you want on the graph when the table is clicked?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. What have you tried, where didn't it work? Mouse down & mouse up events on table rows should be enough..

Comment: conca: Graph should show aggregate information referring over the data I have selected in the table; and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/x1jGW0lqKyzV7EKsVAbJ?p=preview

Here is the example of how you could do it.

Once you create an directive to connect your data with the DOM, then
it is simple matter of handling the data model through template.

I reused the flot integration directive that I used for other project.
(This 'reusability' is what I love about AngularJs.)